# Regular expression : Excluding last part

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking to apply a regular expression to an input string.

Regular expression:`(.*)\\(.*)_(.*)_(.*)-([0-9]{4}).*`

Test entries:

- Parkman\L9\B137598_00_T-3298-B
- Parkman\L9\B137598_00_T-3298

The result should be B137598_00_T-3298 for both test entries. The problem is that if I add 4 digits in the test entries, the result will be, for example, B137598_00_T-3298-5555.

What I need here is that anything after the 3298 should not be taken into account.
What are the changes that I can perform to make that possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single capture group with a bit more specific pattern:

```
\w\\\w+\\((?:[^\W_]+_){2}[^\W_]+-[0-9]{4})\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w` Match a single word char
- `\\\w+\\` Match 1+ word chars between backslashes
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:[^\W_]+_){2}` Repeat 2 times word chars without `_` followed by a single `_`
  - `[^\W_]+-` Match 1+ word chars without `_` and then `-`
  - `-[0-9]{4}` Match `-` and 4 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Sln5X/1)

Or a bit broader pattern with a match only, where `\w` also matches an underscore, and asserting `\` to the left:

```
(?<=\\)\w+-[0-9]{4}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IaGR5/1)

Answer (score 0):

c# code:

```
        string s1 = @"Parkman\\L9\\B137598_00_T-3298-B";
        string s2 = @"Parkman\L9\B137598_00_T-3298";
        string pattern = @"\w+_[0-9]{2}_T-[0-9]{4}";

        var match = Regex.Matches( s1, pattern);
        Console.WriteLine("s1: {0}", match[0]);

        match = Regex.Matches(s2, pattern);
        Console.WriteLine("s2: {0}" , match[0]);
```

then the result:

> s1: B137598_00_T-3298

> s2: B137598_00_T-3298